# create object output stream from an object

Tags: java, database, jdbc, objectoutputstream

I want to create on `ObjectOutputStream`, but I don't want to persist the object in a file, so how to do that? All the tutorials(that I found) say only about the file way:

```
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("t.tmp");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(new Date());
        oos.close();
```

I want to store the object into a database, so I need to specify a stream in method `setBinaryStream()` from class `PreparedStatement`.

Thanks for answering...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Store it in a byte array instead. You can use [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) for this. This way you can use [`PreparedStatement#setBytes()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBytes%28int,%20byte[]%29).

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
oos.writeObject(new Date());
oos.close();
// ...
preparedStatement.setBytes(i, baos.toByteArray());
```

---

That said, this is pretty a good smell. Are you sure that you need to serialize Java objects into a database? This way they are unindexable and unsearchable. If you for example store each `Person` serialized in the DB, you cannot do `SELECT * FROM person WHERE name = 'John'` anymore. The normal practice is to do a 1:1 mapping of the entity and the DB table. The `Date` for example can perfectly be stored in a `DATETIME`/`TIMESTAMP` column.

Comment: I definitely know this is not a good practice, which is in my opinion no justification for not knowing this way of programming :-)

Comment: Okay, let's assume that you know what you're doing :) You're welcome.

Answer (score 6):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
os.writeObject(new Date());
os.close();

byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
```

So now you have a byte array and do what you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

you specifically need to use an outputstream to write to a database? I would seriously consider looking at the persistence api before attempting to write an outputstream implementation.. since connection details etc, might get tricky to manage.

have a look at [link text](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2EE/jpa/) and remember it can be used in J2SE as well.